# Why does my div not change it's display mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After clicking on the "button" div, the chk() function is called. In the if statement (inside of the chk() function), the else if does not work. It's supposed to set an other divs display mode to block (before that, the display is set to none).

I've tried using different things to see if the else if is acctually happening, but nothing inside of it works (i tried putting a temporary alert(), using .innerHTML ect.). It's as if the else if isn't even there. On the other hand the first if works perfectly. It's only the else if causing the problem.

HTML / JS

```
<script>
    function chk()
    {
        var login = document.getElementById("l").value;
        var haslo = document.getElementById("h").value;

        if(login == "adam123" && haslo == "haslo321")
        {
            window.location.href = "strTabelka.html";
        }
        else if(login != "adam123" || haslo != "haslo321")
        {
            docuemnt.getElementById("errorBox").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>

    login: adam123<br>
    haslo: haslo321
    <div id="logbg">
        Logowanie
        <div id="logbox">
            Login <input type="text" id="l"><br><br>
            Hasło <input type="text" id="h">
            <div id="button" onclick="chk();">Zaloguj się</div>
            <div id="errorBox">Nieprawidłowy login lub hasło!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS for the button and errorBox divs

```
#button
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width:200px;
    height:35px;
    border:3px solid #ff6600;
    border-radius: 14px;
    padding-top:3px;
}
#button:hover
{
    background-color: #ff6600;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#errorBox
{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:5px;
    display:none;
}
```

Basically, the if statement checks if the user has typed in the correct login and password. If the user didn't, the errorBox (that contains a message saying in polish: "incorrect username or password") changes it's display mode from none to block which makes the message visible.
PS. sorry for the polish language here and there ("haslo means "password" in polish :D )

Comment: There is a typo in your "else if part": It has to be "document" !

Comment: I hope you don't really do authentication purely in javascript? You do know javascript is server to the browser and visible to the user? Also what is the point of the else if, it checks the same thing the else if there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss spelled document, changed it and it worked. thanks

```
 docuemnt.getElementById("errorBox").style.display = "block";
```

```js
function chk() {
  var login = document.getElementById("l").value;
  var haslo = document.getElementById("h").value;

  if (login == "adam123" && haslo == "haslo321") {
    window.location.href = "strTabelka.html";
  } else if (login != "adam123" || haslo != "haslo321") {
    document.getElementById("errorBox").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#button {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 3px solid #ff6600;
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

#button:hover {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#errorBox {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
login: adam123<br> haslo: haslo321
<div id="logbg">
  Logowanie
  <div id="logbox">
    Login <input type="text" id="l"><br><br> Hasło <input type="text" id="h">
    <div id="button" onclick="chk();">Zaloguj się</div>
    <div id="errorBox">Nieprawidłowy login lub hasło!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, i'm actually ashamed by this stupid mistake. Thank you very much for you're time :D

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your JavaScript code. You have written `docuemnt` instead of `document` in your last line of code before braces. That's why it is not working.

```js
function chk() {
  var login = document.getElementById("l").value;
  var haslo = document.getElementById("h").value;

  if (login == "adam123" && haslo == "haslo321") {
    window.location.href = "strTabelka.html";
  } else if (login != "adam123" || haslo != "haslo321") {
    document.getElementById("errorBox").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#button {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 3px solid #ff6600;
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

#button:hover {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#errorBox {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
login: adam123<br> haslo: haslo321
<div id="logbg">
  Logowanie
  <div id="logbox">
    Login <input type="text" id="l"><br><br> Hasło <input type="text" id="h">
    <div id="button" onclick="chk();">Zaloguj się</div>
    <div id="errorBox">Nieprawidłowy login lub hasło!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```